# looking up Swing components by their id?

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to get a reference to a swing object via some lookup method ??

Keeping a multitude of instance variables for every single UI element seems to be such an overkill

ie kinda the way its done in javascript:

```
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
ta.setId("myJTextArea");
....
....
....
JTextArea ta = window.getElementById("myJTextArea");
ta.setTexT("blah");
```

*PS.* I'm not writing software for space shuttle columbia. This is a quick and dirty projects, so best practices dont apply. Thx.

Comment: "Keeping a multitude of instance variables for every single UI element seems to be such an overkill"  As opposed to keeping a multitude of Strings that represent field names, then using some type of 'lookup' system that cannot be verified at compile-time?

Comment: correct, less lines of code => easier to read. also dont need to pass reference to anything into methods that update the said elements, etc etc.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve in a non-programming sense that you feel that this is necessary?  This sounds as if you need to refactor your code as a better solution.  Though I've sometimes used HashMap<String, JTextField> when it best solves a problem, for instance when I create a data entry form on the fly and use the same JLabel Strings as the HashMap key Strings.

Comment: It was a simple question for clarification of your problem. And "best programming practices" are what we all need to learn and apply, whether this appeals to you or not.

Comment: "I'm not writing software for space shuttle columbia."  OK.  But if you code like that, you might end up with the same result (crash & burn). "..dont need to pass reference to anything into methods that update the said elements,.."  How do you determine which of the 'multitude' of text areas to update unless a String identifying the name of the field is passed to the method?  Seems just as complicated, and far more error prone, than passing the variable itself (which will not only check at compile time that it exists, but also that it is an object of the correct type for the method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static Component getComponentById(Container container, String componentId){

        if(container.getComponents().length > 0)
        {
            for(Component c : container.getComponents())
            {
                if(componentId.equals(c.getName()))
                {
                    return c;
                }
                if(c instanceof Container)
                {
                    return getComponent((Container) c, componentId);
                }
            }
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Comment: I think that last call to getComponent() should really be a call to getComponentById().